# Scala: change value in list inside a map

Tags: scala, list, dictionary

I'm facing a problem:
I want to change one element inside but the code is changing all elements.
I must be doing something wrong.
Here's what I have:

```
var critics: Map[String, List[(String, Double)]] = Map(
  "First" -> List(("a", 1.0), ("b", 2.0)),
  "Second" -> List(("c", 3.0), ("d", 4.0))
  )

  def setNewRating(keyMap: String, param1: String, newRating: Double) = {
    val newList = critics(keyMap).map{case (param1, _) => (param1, newRating); case x => x}
    critics = critics + (keyMap -> newList)
    }

    println(critics)

    setNewRating("First", "b", 5.0)

    println(critics)
```

so, I'm looking for the key "First" and getting the List I want to change the "b" from 2.0 to 5.0 but the result I'm getting is:

```
critics: Map[String,List[(String, Double)]] = Map(First -> List((a,1.0), (b,2.0)), Second -> List((c,3.0), (d,4.0)))
setNewRating: (keyMap: String, param1: String, newRating: Double)Unit
Map(First -> List((a,1.0), (b,2.0)), Second -> List((c,3.0), (d,4.0)))
Map(First -> List((a,5.0), (b,5.0)), Second -> List((c,3.0), (d,4.0)))
```

The code changed all the values!

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `param1` in backticks:

```
  def setNewRating(keyMap: String, param1: String, newRating: Double) = {
    val newList = critics(keyMap)
     .map { 
       case (`param1`, _) => param1 -> newRating 
       case x => x
     }
     critics = critics + (keyMap -> newList)
  }
```

The problem is that `case (param1, _)` means "match anything, and store the value into new local variable `param1`". That's not what you want.

```
 case (`param1`, _) =>
```

On the other hand, means "match the value that is the same as the outer variable `param1`".

Alternatively, if you renamed `param1` to `Param1`, it would work too (apparently, scala matching assumes that everything starting with a capital letter is constant). I am not suggesting you do that, only mentioning it for completeness. Just use backticks.

(Also, using `var` like this makes me cringe, you really should find a way to avoid it, but that wasn't your question ...)

Comment: Yes, I also don't like this var thing but I'm not sure how can I do it in a "scala way" (I have a java background) ! Maybe returning a new Map from the method?

Comment: Yes, returning a new map, is the way. Also, passing it in as an input would be a good idea ("good" functions do not cause side effects, and do not depend on data from outside): `println(setNewRating(critics, "First", "b", 5))`

Answer (score 1):

This should work. the `param1` you use in the case clause `.map{case (param1, _)` is not the same variable param1 defined in the argument. It is a new variable `param1` which is assigned the value of the first element of the `Tuple2` that shadows the method argument.

```
def setNewRating(keyMap: String, param1: String, newRating: Double) = {
  val newList = critics(keyMap) map {
    case (x, _) if x == param1 => (param1, newRating)
    case x => x
  }
  critics = critics + (keyMap -> newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change from `List` to `Set`, you might just be missing `MultiMap` trait.

> A trait for mutable maps with multiple values assigned to a key.
>
> This class is typically used as a mixin. It turns maps which map A to Set[B] objects into multimaps that map A to B objects.

You can find the reference [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html)